# using jquery .not with .on handler binder

Tags: jquery

I have a function as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".songTilesGenreContainer", function () {
    if ($(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").hasClass("minimalized")) {
        $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").removeClass("minimalized");
        $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").addClass("maximized");
        $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").removeClass("maximized");
        $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").addClass("minimalized");
        $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Whenever user clicks on the .songTilesGenreContainer it is going to slideDown or slideUp depending on which class it has. The problem is that in that container I have some elements that I can click on and I would like the .songTilesGenreContainer not to slideUp when I click on the specified elements. To my knowledge by using the .not function does exactly what I want but how would I use it with the .on event handler?
Thanks

Comment: you should chain your stuff and cache your selectors so you aren't executing that find so many times. `var $myThing = $('.actualTilesContainer', $(this));` `$myThing.removeClass().addClass().slideDown();`

Comment: side note: are you sure there's not a more efficient listener than document? It should be the closest ancestor that is not at risk of being destroyed/modified in such a way that the binding is lost.

Comment: I used document because that is howit was written in jquery documentation example, not sure if there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to all those elements for which you don't want to execute the required code. In the click handler check for event target and if it has that class then just don't do anything. Try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".songTilesGenreContainer", function (e) {

        //Check if the target has that class
        if($(e.target).hasClass("className")){
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }

        if ($(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").hasClass("minimalized")) {
            $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").removeClass("minimalized");
            $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").addClass("maximized");
            $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").slideDown();
        }
        else {
             $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").removeClass("maximized");
            $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").addClass("minimalized");
            $(this).find(".actualTilesContainer").slideUp();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: ok my bad.. finnaly it's working,  if($(e.target).hasClass("className")).. I was typing in .myclass instead of myclass..

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$('.actualTilesContainer').toggleClass('maximized'); //have minimised class as default
$('.actualTilesContainer').slideToggle();
```

I think the if statements you have are unnecessary especially for jQuery.

So the final code looks like:

```
$('.songTilesGenreContainer').on('click', '.songTilesGenreContainer', function(){

    $('.actualTilesContainer').toggleClass('maximized'); //have minimised class as default
    $('.actualTilesContainer').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: in jquery documentation it said that since version 1.7 it is recommended no to use .live but use .on

Answer (score 1):

You should bind a click handler to the childs and then do a

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

That will stop the click from bubbling to the ".songTilesGenreContainer" parent!

Answer (score 1):

What kind of elements are they ? If they have a click handler attached to them, then you could do like so:

```
var $elements = $( ".songTilesGenreContainer" );

$elements.find(".elementsYouDontWantToTriggerSlideUp").on("click", function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    // do your stuff
});

// toggle handler is attached >after< (it won't work otherwise, as handlers
// are executed in their bind order)
$elements.on( "click", function( ev ) {
    // >>>> ALWAYS <<<< cache you elements is you reuse them, or use chaining
    var $elelements = $( this ).find(".actualTilesContainer");

    $elelements.toggleClass("minimalized maximized").slideToggle();
});
```

If they don't have already an handler, you can do like that:

```
$(".whatEver").on( "someevent", function( ev ) {
    // ev.target contains the actual element that was clicked
    var $target = $( ev.target );

    // then you could use
    $target.is('.someSelector' )
    // to see if the element that was clicked should "trigger" or not the effect

});
```

Comment: tried this, but didn't really work for me, and created more mess

Comment: ok. So could you add some HTML content to your snippet and explain what do you want to do ? Which elements should/shouldn't trigger the effect ? :)